# React hook useState method updates array unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning React hook and tried to update an array value. What I want to achieve is when the button is clicked, the name and the counter of the first element perform the +1 operation. However, the code performs the operation twice instead. So the button shows

**Initial**: Click 0 FirstArgument

**Click 1**: Click 1 FirstArgument1

**Click 2**: Click 3 FirstArgument111

**Click 3**: Click 5 FirstArgument11111

...

Here is the code snipe:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function HookCount() {
  const initState = [
    {
      counter: 0,
      name: "FirstArgument",
    },
    "SecondArgument",
  ];

  const [variable, setCount] = useState(initState);

  const setStateFun = () => {
    setCount((prevVariable) => {
      let updateList = [...variable];
      updateList[0].name = prevVariable[0].name + 1;
      updateList[0].counter = prevVariable[0].counter + 1;
      updateList[1] = prevVariable[1];
      return updateList;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setStateFun}>
        Click {variable[0].counter} {variable[0].name}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HookCount;
```

The questions that I have are:

1. Why the code behaves like that. What I did wrong or what is the proper way to achieve this.
2. If I replace `let updateList = [...variable];` with `let updateList = prevVariable;` the state does not change anymore. Why can't we use `prevVariable` instead of spread the array here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `setCount` or `variable` defined anywhere it your code, so I cannot guess how you implemented them. However, `setStateFun` is just overcomplicated.

By using the [functional](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) `setState`, you already have access to `prevVariable`. To perform the increment, it can be simplified like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [variable, setCount] = useState([
    {
      counter: 0,
      name: "FirstArgument"
    },
    "SecondArgument"
  ]);

  const setStateFun = () => {
    setCount(prevVariable => [
      {
        counter: prevVariable[0].counter + 1,
        name: prevVariable[0].name + 1
      },
      prevVariable[1]
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setStateFun}>
        Click {variable[0].counter} {variable[0].name}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See it here:

[image: Edit nameless-pine-4hsbj]

Comment: I accidentally deleted the definition when I was removing some old comment in the code... The definition "const [variable, setCount] = useState(initState);" was placed between the definition and the state initialization.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon! The code that you provided works! However, I am still curious why the implementation that I put over there will cause the state changes twice (it seems to me that it was rendered twice for one button click)